# add a new column with scaled values to all dataframes in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes, all of which contain a user column and another column called 'VD'. I want to add a new column to all dataframes 'VD_z' in the list with the scaled values of the VD column

```
df1 <- data.frame(VD = 1:3, user=letters[1:3])
df2 <- data.frame(VD = 4:6, user=letters[4:6])
filelist <- list(df1,df2)
```

I read several similar questions, finally trying:

```
filelist <- mapply(cbind(filelist, VD_z= lapply(filelist, function(df) scale(df$VD))))
```

What I expect is that all dataframes in the list now have the new VD_z column with the scaled values, like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(VD = 1:3, user=letters[1:3], VD_z=c(-1,0,1))
df2 <- data.frame(VD = 4:6, user=letters[4:6], VD_z=c(-1,0,1))
```

What I get is an Error message 'Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` from `purrr` to loop through the `list` and `mutate` to create the 'VD_z'

```
library(tidyverse)
filelist %>%
      map( ~ .x %>% 
                mutate(VD_z = scale(VD)))
```

---

or using `base R` with `lapply/transform`

```
filelist1 <- lapply(filelist, transform, VD_z = scale(VD))
filelist1
#[[1]]
#  VD user VD_z
#1  1    a   -1
#2  2    b    0
#3  3    c    1

#[[2]]
#  VD user VD_z
#1  4    d   -1
#2  5    e    0
#3  6    f    1
```

---

If we using the logic from the `OP's post, assign the`scale`to new coumn 'VD_z' and then`return` 'df'

```
filelist1 <- lapply(filelist, function(df) {df$VD_z <- scale(df$VD); df})
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` approach can be,

```
library(data.table)

dd <- rbindlist(filelist, idcol = 'id')[, VD_z := scale(VD), by = id]
#   id VD user VD_z
#1:  1  1    a   -1
#2:  1  2    b    0
#3:  1  3    c    1
#4:  2  4    d   -1
#5:  2  5    e    0
#6:  2  6    f    1
```

You can then use `split()` to split the data frame to a list, i.e.

```
split(dd, dd$id)
```

which gives,

> ```
> $`1`
>    id VD user VD_z
> 1:  1  1    a   -1
> 2:  1  2    b    0
> 3:  1  3    c    1
>
> $`2`
>    id VD user VD_z
> 1:  2  4    d   -1
> 2:  2  5    e    0
> 3:  2  6    f    1
> ```